# Output of each value of loop in a different cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to create a loop for a formula which would be repeated throughout for a value entered.

How can I get the value of each iteration of loop separately in a different cell like it shows in the immediate print window?

```
'p1 this is the the formula i want to loop of different values
For i = Sheet1.Range("C1").Value To Sheet1.Range("C1").Value + 150 Step 50
  w = 10 * 100 ^ 0.8 * i ^ 1.8 * 10 ^ 0.2
  Debug.Print i
  Debug.Print w
Next i
```

> debug print screen

[image]

I have just started using VBA and have no prior coding experience.
any help is greatly appreciated

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't share *where* the values should go so this is just showing you how you can dynamically refer to a cell on worksheet with VBA.

---

In this format the column is hard coded (*i.e. static/enclosed in quotes*) and the row is variable. In this instance the row is tied to `r` which we increment by 1 in every loop (otherwise we will just continuously overwrite the same cell). Usually you can tie this to your variable `i` but since you have `Step 50` this won't work (*given you would have 50 blank cells in between each output to the worksheet*).

You may want to change `r` starting with `r = 1` each time and instead start `r` at the last free cell in a given column. If so then replace `r = 1` with  `r = ws.Range("D" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row`. This will create a running list of all of the values of `w` and `i` that won't be overwritten every time you run the macro

```
Sub Try()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim Target As Long, i As Long, r As Long, w As Double

Target = ws.Range("C1").Value
r = 1

For i = Target To (Target + 150) Step 50
    w = 10 * 100 ^ 0.8 * i ^ 1.8 * 10 ^ 0.2
    
    ws.Range("D" & r) = i
    ws.Range("E" & r) = w
    
    r = r + 1
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to create a user-defined function (UDF) which will be used as a cell formula?

```
Public Function MyCalc(ByVal x as double) as Double
    MyCalc = 10 * 100 ^ 0.8 * x ^ 1.8 * 10 ^ 0.2
End Function
```

Add the function definition in a module and then call it from the worksheet

[image: scr]